# C# Generic Base Polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

i have one generic base class and two classes derived from base class. I want to create this kind of derived classes with a object factory. But i can not do this with a generic base class. I can do this, this way, in Java without any problems. I also solved this in c# with boxing and unboxing. What is the proper way to do this ?

```
public abstract class Base<T> {
    public abstract T Value {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base<int> {
    int value;

    public override int Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
        set {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base<float> {
    float value;

    public override float Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
        set {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Factory {
    public Base create(int type) {
        switch(type) {
            case 1:
                return new Derived1();
            case 2:
                return new Derived2();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Solved : I understand that since any interface won't have the generic method they also won't help. Only solution is boxing the value into an object. Here is my solution.

```
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract object Value {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base {
    int value;

    public override object Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
        set {
            this.value = (int) value;
        }
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base {
    float value;

    public override object Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
        set {
            this.value = (float) value;
        }
    }
}

public class Factory {
    public Base create(int type) {
        switch(type) {
            case 1:
                return new Derived1();
            case 2:
                return new Derived2();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i can treat all derived objects as Base object.

Comment: I am kind of lost. What's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: This is adequate as long as you don't mind continuing to add an `int` value assignment as you add supported types for your `Factory`. ...except as @PeterA.Schneider notes, you have to have a non-generic `Base<T>` returned.

Comment: @TyCobb I guess you cannot use `Base` like that; you must decide between `Base<int>` or `Base<float>` which kindof defeats the purpose.

Comment: The solution is, of course, to make `Factory.create()` generic. (Yes, what you said now, @TyCobb.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Awww I missed just the `Base` signature in the Factory. Generics would have to be propagated up to the `create` call

Comment: You need `Factory.create()` to be able to return a single type, regardless of base class. The only way to do that is for the base class to implement an interface and return that interface type instead of the base class, or to have a non-generic base class from which the generic base class derives. There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow already which address this fundamental aspect of OOP programming.

Comment: I'm wondering how that is supposed to work in Java. Does the Java type erasure in templates permit that?

Comment: In reality, you kind of need to do the generics all the way up because what is `Value` supposed to be or be used. No matter what since C# is statically typed, anywhere you need the `int` you'll need a way to tell the compiler it is an int. So either you are stuck casting everything everywhere and hope your casts were correct or you just change your factory to be generic.

Comment: May be i couldn't explain well. after factory, i want to access Value propery of each object regardless from its type. for example : Base d1 = new Factory().Create(1); d1.Value should return me the integer value.

Comment: Rather than editing an answer into the question itself, please go ahead and answer your own question.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), [Editing the question such that it answers itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201874) and [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434) for why.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to have a non-generic `Base<T>` return type;
You might consider using `TypeCode`:

```
public class Factory {
    public Base<T> create<T>() {
        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T));
        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Empty:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Object:
                break;
            case TypeCode.DBNull:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Char:
                break;
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:  // Derived1 : Base<int>
                return new Derived1();

                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Single:  // Derived2 : Base<float>
                return new Derived2();

                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                break;
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                break;
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                break;
            case TypeCode.String:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

...also, if you used an interface you can "hide" the `<TypeParam>` from the return:

```
public interface IBase {
    // properties/methods
}
```

Then:

```
public abstract class Base<T> : IBase {
        // properties/methods
}
```

And then:

```
public class Factory {
    public IBase create<T>() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Now, for returning `Value` there are three options: (1) stick with implementation without the interface `IBase`; (2) use `dynamic` return type in the interface, or; (3) *box* the values in `object` as you have done.

**NOTE: writing off the top of my head, untested.**

```
// 1. implementation without the interface    
public abstract class Base<T> {
    public abstract T Value {get; set;}
}

// 2. implementation with IBase
public interface IBase {
    public dynamic Value {get; set;}
}

public abstract Base<T> : IBase {
    public abstract dynamic Value {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Nice on the TypeCode usage instead of a ton of `if(typeof(T)...` checks. +1

Comment: The use of an interface would be a cleaner approach here as well. Maybe if I get unlazy when I get home I'll add that.

Comment: @IAbstract yes i will be thankfull. May be i couldn't explain well. after factory, i want to access Value propery of each object regardless from its type. for example : Base d1 = new Factory().Create(1); d1.Value should return me the integer value.

Comment: @e.imer That only works in a dynamic language. Since C# is statically typed, it has to know what type the value will be when you use it. You either need to cast to an `int`, ignore the type all together and use `object`, or use generics from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of achieving what you want but the caller of the factory will need to be aware of the type being created. I also changed the properties in your derived classes to automatic properties since you were not doing anything special with them but you can change them back if you wish.

```
public abstract class Base<T> {
   public abstract T Value
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

public class Derived1 : Base<int> {
   public override int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Derived2 : Base<float> {
   public override float Value { get; set; }
}

public class Factory {
   public Base<T> Create<T>(int type) {
      switch( type ) {
         case 1:
         return new Derived1() as Base<T>;
         case 2:
         return new Derived2() as Base<T>;
      }

      return null; // or whatever you want to do
   }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
var f = new Factory();
var one = f.Create<int>( 1 );
var two = f.Create<float>( 2 );
```

Like I mentioned the caller of the factory needs some knowledge of the types being created because this will fail:

```
var f = new Factory();
var one = f.Create<int>( 2 );   // <-------- Changed from 1 to 2
var two = f.Create<float>( 1 ); // <-------- Changed from 2 to 1
```

You can always throw an exception from the factory to explain why you could not create the type requested so callers can then take the appropriate steps.

Comment: May be i couldn't explain well. after factory, i want to access Value propery of each object regardless from its type. for example : Base d1 = new Factory().Create(1); d1.Value should return me the integer value.